# spinner that trigger another spinenr

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        // my code here, but I don't know how..
    }
}
```

I think it will be something like this:

1. get the selected item position of mySpinner
2. `switch(pos)`
3. Update spinner entries? I don't know...

I'm not sure what to do for the last step. Help?

Comment: what do you mean with trigger another spinner, what should be achieved?

Comment: spinner selection that load another spinner lists.. eg. spinner1 i selected car, then the 2nd spinner show a list of "GTR", "SkyLine" etc

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
    car.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            itemSelected = arg2;
              // add items to the cardetails spinner's adapter using the itemselected  and refresh the adapter using nofifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
    cardetails.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
```

here car and cardetails are spinners
you need to refresh the adapter that is related to the car spinner so that the spinner also gets refreshed

Comment: they are just 2 diff spinner.. =="